# Does Windows log when you plug in / unplug an audio device from a 3.5mm jack?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

**Question**: When an audio device is plugged in or unplugged from the 3.5mm jack, does Windows log that anywhere? Where can I find this?

**Background**: I came back to my desk grabbing coffee and found that my buds were unplugged when I started a podcast. As fringe political shenanigans blared throughout the office, I thought to myself: "sabotage." Someone unplugged my buds while I was gone, hoping that I'd get myself into hot water in just such a way as this. I'll fight this all the way to the supreme court. I'll start a twitter hashtag campaign, #SaveThaler.

Of course it's also possible that I actually had just left them unplugged and forgot. So I want to see if there was a log for an unplugging around the time I stepped away for coffee.

Thanks.

Comment: Not by default. You have to write an app to detect plug in/plug out and then generate a user defined event. See [Device Events - Windows applications | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/device-events)

Comment: Okay, sounds like this is the answer. If you'd like to repost as an answer rather than a comment, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Answer posted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When an audio device is plugged/unplugged from the 3.5mm jack, does Windows log that anywhere?

Not by default. You have to write an app to detect plug in/plug out. Note the jack has to support **jack-presence detection**.

> A device event notifies clients of a change in the status of an audio
>   endpoint device in the system. The following are examples of device
>   events:
>
> - The user enables or disables an audio endpoint device from Device Manager or from the Windows multimedia control panel, Mmsys.cpl.
> - The user adds an audio adapter to the system or removes an audio adapter from the system.
> - **The user plugs an audio endpoint device into an audio jack with jack-presence detection, or removes an audio endpoint device from such
>     a jack.**
> - The user changes the device role that is assigned to a device.
> - The value of a property of a device changes.

See [Device Events - Windows applications | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/device-events) for more information and sample code.

You can extend the sample code to log to a file or create a custom user define event in the event log.

Suggestion:

- Add code to use your built in webcam to take a photo of the culprit.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the driver that enables the jack does logging by default?

Comment: It's possible, but mine don't.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Windows log when you plug in / unplug any audio device?

Every operating system must know (or be aware of) any type of hardware changes, for example, when user adds or removes any hardware device, allocate resources, install required driver etc. In Windows, there are two main services for Audio manging. Those are Windows Audio (Audiosrv) and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder (AudioEndpointBuilder) manage audio devices and audio streaming for programs. So, the awareness of any device change is an essential path of an OS.

> Does Windows log that anywhere? Where can I find this?

Does Windows collect it as telemetry? As an end-user, we don't know it. But it is possible to collect the "Event Logs" with some programs. We need to install [Windows Driver Kit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).

**Procedure:** Run these command in command prompt

- Get the Audio logging providers: `WevtUtil.exe enum-logs | find "Audio"`
- Get event provider GUID of Audio logging provider: `WevtUtil.exe get-publisher "Microsoft-Windows-Audio" | find "guid"`
- Start a real time event tracing session: `TraceLog.exe -start MyTrace -guid #AE4BD3BE-F36F-45B6-8D21-BDD6FB832853 -rt`
- Show event logs: `TraceFmt.exe -rt MyTrace -displayonly`

Do not start any audio or video files otherwise command prompt window populates with too many events. Now plug in and out your audio device. The CMD window will show the event logs. Use `TraceLog.exe -stop MyTrace` to stop that event trace session. For further details, see [TraceLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tracelog) and [TraceFmt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tracefmt) documentations.